# V doing vs to do

Tags: meaning

Can I replace the V-ing term with to do term in this specific case？ Is there any semantic diiference between these two sentences?

> The extended abstract should consist of text and appropriate figures supporting the key message.
>
> The extended abstract should consist of text and appropriate figures to support the key message.

Answer (score 1):

Gerund vs infinitive is one of the more tricky aspects of English.

In your example sentences, there is no difference in meaning between

> text and appropriate figures **supporting** the key message

and

> text and appropriate figures **to support** the key message.

However, the second form would be preferable.

A good tutorial is [here](https://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/)